# Is there a way to access the help FAQ from mobile app?

Tags: discussion, android-app, help-center

While using the mobile app I was wanting to see the /help page but could not find a way to get to it.  Is there a way?  If not, is it possible for new users to create an account from the app and not be able to access the site rules?

Comment: Android or iOS?

Comment: Android. I didn't know the app was on the app store yet

Comment: Faq can be viewed from the app by searching for the faq tag. However the help centre can't be viewed